# Tables are detected when running migration, but aren't created in database

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, alembic, flask-migrate

I ran a migration to create the SQLite tables for a [cookiecutter](https://github.com/wdm0006/cookiecutter-flask) Flask app.  Although the database file exists and I can open it, I cannot see the tables.  When I try to create a user I get a "no such table" error.  Why doesn't the table exist even though I ran the migration?  How can I use the tables?

```
$ python manage.py db migrate
INFO  [alembic.migration] Context impl SQLiteImpl.
INFO  [alembic.migration] Will assume non-transactional DDL.
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'tags'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'users'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'posts'
INFO  [alembic.autogenerate.compare] Detected added table 'tags_posts'
Generating C:\envs\r2\myflaskapp\migrations\versions\....
```

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError OperationalError: (OperationalError) no such table:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only generated the migration, you need to apply it as well. Be sure to read through the generated migration file to ensure it's correct before running it.

```
python manage.py db upgrade
```

Applying generated migrations is described in the docs for both [Alembic](https://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#running-our-first-migration) (the migration engine) and [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#example) (the manage commands).